# error: The model expects 3 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (10, 20, 50, 50, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

```
 main_model = Sequential()
 main_model.add(Conv3D(32, 3, 3,3, input_shape=(20,50,50,1)))' 
 main_model.add(Activation('relu'))
 main_model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2))
 main_model.add(Conv3D(64, 3, 3,3))
 main_model.add(Activation('relu'))
 main_model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2)))
 main_model.add(Dropout(0.8))
 main_model.add(Flatten())

 #lower features model - CNN2
 lower_model1 = Sequential()
 lower_model1.add(Conv3D(32, 3, 3,3, input_shape=(20,50,50,1))) 
 lower_model1.add(Activation('relu'))
 lower_model1.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2))) 
 lower_model1.add(Dropout(0.8))
 lower_model1.add(Flatten())

 #lower features model - CNN3
 lower_model2 = Sequential()
 lower_model2.add(Conv3D(32, 3, 3,3, input_shape=(20,50,50,1))) 
 lower_model2.add(Activation('relu'))
 lower_model2.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2))) 
 lower_model2.add(Dropout(0.8))
 lower_model2.add(Flatten()) 

 merged_model = Merge([main_model, lower_model1,lower_model2],mode='concat') 
 final_model = Sequential()
 final_model.add(merged_model)
 final_model.add(Dense(1024,init='normal'))
 final_model.add(Activation('relu'))
 final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 final_model.add(Dense(2,init='normal'))
 final_model.add(Activation('softmax')) 
 final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=
 ['accuracy'])
 train=train_data[-10:]
 test=train_data[-2:]
 X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,20,50,50,1)
 Y = [i[1] for i in train]
 test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,20,50,50,1)
 test_y = [i[1] for i in test]
 final_model.fit(np.array(X),np.array(Y),validation_data=
 (np.array(test_x),np.array(test_y)),batch_size=batch_size,nb_epoch = 
 nb_epoch,validation_split=0.2,shuffle=True,verbose=1)
```

i'm using 50x50 images contained in 20 chunk and that's y my numpy array is 20x50x50
[1st and 2nd models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfeDc.jpg)I'm using sequential model for multi scale 3d cnn network...i don't know y i'm getting this kind of result

[see val_acc,val_loss stays the same in every epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUAan.jpg)

Comment: Any help can be much appreciated

Comment: Please edit your post, add some code and format it as well

Comment: @M.Situation pls help me...if u don't understand my code say ur email i will mail you....thanks for your kind response.....i'm a newbie to stackoverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @M.Situation i formatted...pls see

Comment: also getting another error: The model expects 3 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (10, 20, 50, 50, 1)

Comment: Try `categorical_crossentropy` loss.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko pls see my code may be u can help me with something