# TypeError: Input tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", dtype=float32) (missing Keras metadata)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

my input variables

```
IMG_SIZE_PX=50
SLICE_COUNT=20

n_classes=2

x=tf.placeholder('float')
y=tf.placeholder('float')

keep_rate=0.8
keep_prob=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

my convolution 3d function

```
def conv3d(x, W):
return tf.nn.conv3d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

my maxpooling 3d function

```
def maxpool3d(x):
return tf.nn.max_pool3d(x, ksize=[1,2,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,2,1], 
padding='SAME')
```

this is my network

```
def convolutional_neural_network(x):
```

my network weights

```
weights = {'W_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,1,32])),

           'W_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,3,32,64])),
            'W_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([ 54080 ,1024])),#here 54080 
is the input tensor value
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}
```

my network biases

```
biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
           'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
            'b_fc':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
           'out':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
```

here is my input x

```
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, IMG_SIZE_PX, IMG_SIZE_PX, SLICE_COUNT, 1])
```

my 2 hidden layers(convolution+maxpooling)

```
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
conv1 = maxpool3d(conv1)
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
conv2 = maxpool3d(conv2)
```

my fully connected layer

```
 fc = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1,  54080 ])
fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)
```

my output layer

```
output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out'])+biases['out']
return output
```

my input numpy arrays

```
much_data = np.load('D:/muchdata-50-50-20.npy')
train_data = much_data[-10:]
validation_data = much_data[-2:]
```

finally training my network

```
 def train_neural_network(x):
 outl = convolutional_neural_network(x)#don't know this is my output 
layer
 model=Model(input=x, output=outl)
 model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=
['accuracy'])
train_neural_network(x)#train the net
```

my error is this[keras meta data is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txZOF.jpg)
any help can be appreciated

Comment: Why are you defining your model with plain TensorFlow, but then using Keras to build the model? You can use Keras to define and build the model, using TensorFlow directly is not necessary in most cases if you use Keras.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro bcoz i'm trying to create a model and find probability....i tried sequential model too but it gave me same val_acc,val_loss for every epoch and then i tried multi scale cnn and got some input missing keras metadata as u can see here nobody answered "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476708/error-the-model-expects-3-input-arrays-but-only-received-one-array-found-arr" so i tried in tensorflow Saver but it has some restore error so i left that one and finally i tried this and it got me here.

Comment: @Manigandan_v Unfortunately you didn't answer my question, I would recommend do everything properly with the Keras Functional API.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes i tried that too it too gave me same val_acc,val_loss for every epoch....atleast pls help with this one"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476708/error-the-model-expects-3-input-arrays-but-only-received-one-array-found-arr"

Comment: Without knowing where you define and where you use the placeholder that's causing the problem it's hard to know how to fix it. In general Matias's suggestion to use keras to build your model is best.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos pls check this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476708/error-the-model-expects-3-input-arrays-but-only-received-one-array-found-arr